# Equation for camera projection

Tags: camera

I am trying to find an equation for a camera projection.
The goal is to map the point $P(P_x, P_y, P_z)$ from the world coordinates onto the window coordinates $Q(Q_x, Q_y)$.

[image]

The eye of viewing is located a distance D from the $\hat{e_1}$-$\hat{e_2}$ plane, and in the direction of -$\hat{e_3}$.
$\hat{e_1}$, $\hat{e_2}$ and $\hat{e_3}$ are unit vectors.

What is the equation to map P from world coordinates to window coordinates?
$\vec{Q}(Q_x, Q_y) = f(\vec{P}, \hat{e_1}, \hat{e_2}, \hat{e_3}, \vec{v}, \vec{c})$
with all the vectors on the right side described in terms of world coordinates, eg

$\vec{P} = (P_x, P_y, P_z)$

$\vec{C} = (C_x, C_y, C_z)$

$\vec{e_1} = ({e_1}_x, {e_1}_y, {e_1}_z)$

$\vec{e_2} = ({e_2}_x, {e_2}_y, {e_2}_z)$

$\vec{e_3} = ({e_3}_x, {e_3}_y, {e_3}_z)$

Comment: If you don't know where to start, you can work on a simpler version of the problem: instead of projecting from a 3D space to a 2D screen, try projecting from 2D space to a 1D screen. Work one transformation at a time, and the equation in 2D becomes reasonably simple. Then you can redo it in 3D.

Comment: By the way, the convention is usually to name the components of a vector $\vec{V} = (V_x, V_y, V_z)$ rather than $\vec{V} = (x_v, y_v, z_v)$.

Comment: @raindrop - Check this link might come handy. https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/6365/inverse-value-in-a-perspective-matrix/6366#6366

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward matrix math and can be found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection). It's quite elaborate, though, if you want to learn the math behind it and the other types of projection that exist. I will encourage you to checkout either [Real-Time Rendering](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1568814240) or [Computer Graphics, Principles and Practice](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Computer-Graphics-Principles-Practice-Practices/dp/0321399528).

Comment: I accept that the math is elaborate and I will really have to put in the time to study it.